# Mathematica does not evaluate cell to a numerical value

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, logarithm

I simply want to calculate the log[2] e. g. in Mathematica and the result I get is log[2]. The same happens with sin and so on. But it calculates something like 5*5. What is the reason for this? I can't find anything in the settings and I tried some commands too (like calculate).

Comment: Try `N@Log[2]` or `Log[2.0]` and read about [exact numbers](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/Numbers.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first word of the function must be capitalized log -> Log

Log[1.9999999999000005*^-13]
-29.240459028412648`

Answer (score 0):

Try `log[2.]` instead of `log[2]`.

Comment: This works for log but not for sin. What is the reason for this?
Do you know why it doesn't work in a function? In the exported data file stands e. g. log[1.9999999999000005*^-13]